# Powershell custom install shows in Add / Remove Programs

Tags: powershell, installation, addremoveprograms

I've been trying to figure out the following question on the net, but cound't find an answer.

I'm doing custom application installations using Powershell (nothing new here).

Now, I have the following requirement: I would like to add a Comment and a Contact in the Add / Remove Programs, that indicates by which process the application has been installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: just edit them into the reg key under `HKLM...Uninstall`, that's where add/remove pulls from. you'll need to edit `Contact`, `DisplayName` and `Comments` I believe.

Comment: Thx. Would you like to reply me a full answer so i can tag it as a good reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually stumbled on a PS command to do this, thx to ConnorLSW's answer:

```
Set-RegistryKey -key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' + $RegKey -Name "$MyKey" -Value "$MyValue" -Type String
```

where

- `$RegKey` is some (king of UUID) string that identifies your installed application
- `$MyKey` is the field you need to update (in my case, `DisplayName`, `Contact` or `Comments`)
- `$MyValue` is the actual value you want to display in that field

Now it's time for a little caution disclaimer:

**My understanding is that this command can be further generalized to update any registration keys on your machine. Please be very cautious when using it.**

Answer (score 1):

The Add/Remove programs list uses the keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` for all of its information.

if you set the following keys under your program it will change the values in Add/Remove programs.

`DisplayName` for the 'main' title name.

`Contact` for the help address.

`Comments` for any further comments you want in the list.